# Moving a line geometry with three.js using GLSL

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, opengl-es-2.0

I have a line geometry made with three.js, which I want to move as a spermatozoid (i.e. the head moves first, then all of the points along the tail move accordingly to the head) using GLSL.

Here is a visual representation of what I want:

[image]

So as you can see, point **G** eases to (follows) **H**, which in turn follows point **E**, which in turn follows the head.

I have a working examples, being animated on the CPU. Here is the code:

```
class Boid {
  constructor (position) {
    this.position = position
    this.speed = 0.0009 + Math.random() * 0.0003
    this.pointsNum = 12
    this.points = []
    this.line = null
    this.angle = Math.random() * 360

    for (let i = 0; i < this.pointsNum; i += 1) {
      this.points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1))
    }

    this.angle = 0
  }
  update (target, time) {
    if (time) {
      this.line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true
      this.line.geometry.vertices.forEach((p, i) => {
        let nextP = this.line.geometry.vertices[i + 1]
        if (nextP) {
          // if it's not the HEAD point, follow the next point in the geometry vertices
          p.x += (nextP.x - p.x) * (time * 8.0)
          p.y += (nextP.y - p.y) * (time * 8.0)
          p.z += (nextP.z - p.z) * (time * 8.0)
        } else {
          // if the point is in fact the head, ease it according to some random moving point in our scene (target)
          p.x += (target.x - p.x) * time
          p.y += (target.y - p.y) * time
          p.z += (target.z - p.z) * time
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

And here is a working [example](https://codepen.io/gbnikolov/pen/yoJGra).

This technique is working, but would like to accomplish the same stuff with GLSL. My question is how should I approach it? Should I pass the next vertex position to the previous one and ease in my vertex shader? How should I keep track of the next's point position?

Any help is more then appreciated, I have been thinking about this a lot without any success.

Comment: probably the easiest way would be to render the positions in a texture, then read from there

Comment: thanks for your response, i might look into this.. do you have any resources you might recommend?

Comment: Not specifically for this, but gpgpu examples from three are in this space:
https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_gpgpu_birds

Comment: Haven't you found a way? It would be really interesting to do such a thing.